# Getting the current date in bash without spawning a sub-process

Tags: bash, subprocess

This question is pure curiosity. It is easy to get a date by running the `date` command from bash, but it is an external executable and requires spawning a subprocess. I wondered whether it is possible to get the current time/date formatted without a subprocess. I could only find references to date/time formats in the context of `PS1` and `HISTTIMEFORMAT`. The latter allows this:

```
HISTTIMEFORMAT="%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S "
history -s echo
x=$(history)
set -- $x
date="$2"
```

This comes close, but the `$(history)` spawns a subprocess, as far as I can tell.

Can we do better?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`bash` 4.2 introduced a new specifier for `printf`; this was extended in `bash` 4.3 to use the current time if no argument is given. `%()T` expands to the current time, using the format appearing inside the parentheses.

```
$ printf '%(%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S)T\n'
2016-03-25_12:38:10
```

Comment: Cool. I should have read my machine's `man bash` instead of http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash . And nicely, with `printf -v date` I get the date into a variable for further use.

Answer (score 2):

With Linux and GNU bash 4:

```
#!/bin/bash

while IFS=: read -r a b; do 
  [[ $a =~ rtc_time ]] && t="${b// /}"
  [[ $a =~ rtc_date ]] && d="${b// /}"
done < /proc/driver/rtc

echo "$d $t"
```

Output:

```
2016-03-26 08:03:09
```